# Maven: tools.jar not found when executing wsgen

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, wsgen

I try to use `jaxws:wsgen` maven plugin from Windows 8 command line, but it fails with:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory

I know this indicates Maven cannot find tools.jar in my JDK but I don't know how to add this (JDK is installed of course).

Here are some details about my configuration:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:22+0200)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: de_CH, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

So I also tried to add a profile section to my pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default-tools.jar</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>java.vendor</name>
                <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and execute

```
mvn -P default-tools.jar package
```

but I still get the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Full output:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:1.10:wsgen (generate-wsdl) on
>   project WebService: Failed to execute wsgen:
>   com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory:
>   com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:1.10:wsgen
>   (generate-wsdl) on project WebService: Failed to execute wsgen
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute wsgen
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.execute(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:102)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.MainWsGenMojo.execute(MainWsGenMojo.java:14)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>           ... 19 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
>           at com.sun.tools.ws.WsGen.doMain(WsGen.java:69)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.execute(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:97)
>           ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
>           ... 38 more

Also putting the `tools.jar` into my local repository did not solve my problem.

Does anybody has an idea what to try next?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `default-tools.jar` profile is active?   Try `mvn -P default-tools.jar help:active-profiles`.  My guess would be that it isn't.

Comment: This outputs: "The following profiles are active: default-tools.jar" so I guess it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full output (some context what plugin is having problems) would be useful. I'm not entirely sure, but I think that the jaxws maven plugin is missing the classes, not your application, so you should add the dependency to that plugin, not your application.

---

EDIT: OP's code from comment for better read/copy/paste-ability

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <...>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
   <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
   <version>1.7</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few thing you can try: since this is java 7 change the vendor to "Oracle Corporation".

Also are you sure you have this path? ${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar

For testing reason only, you could activate this profile by default and see if that helps, further narrowing the problem.

```
<activation>
  <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

Comment: Changing the vendor did not solve the problem. I am sure about the path becuase changing it to an invalid one (e.g. toolss.jar) in pom.xml leads to a different error saying "Could not find artifact at specified path"

Answer (score 0):

Change your wsdl generator from what you are using to:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

All the configuration is the same, but it works with Java 7 & Java 8 (and openjdk 8, fyi).